# Build Node REST Service that Consumes Other External Services

Tags: node.js, web-services, api

Is it possible to build a Node REST API that references other external services? The sole purpose of this API would be to consolidate other Web services into a single service. Is Node the right technology to choose to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you answer your own questions. First, my apologies for originally calling this an AngularJS API when it's a Node.js API.

You can use the http interfaces to interact with other services. I built a prototype that calls a test service provided by typicode that simply returns its response as a response from my service.

This was built using the node modules express and body-parser.

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// routes
var router = express.Router();

// test route
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: 'Welcome to your API' });   
});

// typicode test route
router.route('/typicode')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    var options = {
      host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
      path: '/posts/1'
    };
    var typicodeReq = http.get(options, function(http_res) {
      var str = '';
      http_res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        str += chunk;
      });
      http_res.on('end', function() {
        res.json(JSON.parse(str));  
      });
    });
  });

// route registration prefixed with /api
app.use('/api', router);

// server start
app.listen(port);
console.log('API Listening on Port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is. Because nodejs is non-blocking and event-driven runtime. It exactly what you need.